# Dash Graph not updating even when callback function runs

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly-dash, dashboard

I've been trying to make a live graph with dash. This is my first time trying out dash but I've come across a problem. I write the callback functions to update the graph according to the update intervals. But even though the function is called(which I verify by adding print statements), the graph itself doesn't update.

```
import os
import dash
from dash import dcc, html
import pandas as pd
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

load_dotenv()
purl = os.environ.get('url')
dbname = 'database'
engine = create_engine(purl + dbname)
table_name = 'SANDBTC'
df = pd.read_sql(table_name.lower(), engine)
print(df)
app_name = 'dash-plots'


def _create_fig():
    df = pd.read_sql(table_name.lower(), engine)
    print(df)
    return go.Figure(
        data=go.Scatter(
            x=df['Time'],
            y=df['result']))


external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)
app.title = 'Graphs'

app.layout = html.Div(children=[html.H1(id='live-text', style={'textAlign': 'center'}),
                                dcc.Graph(
                                    id='dash-graph',
                                    animate=True,
                                    figure=_create_fig()
                                ),
                                dcc.Interval(
                                    id='interval-component',
                                    interval=1000,
                                    n_intervals=0
                                )
                                ], className="container")


@app.callback(Output('live-text', 'children'),
              [Input('interval-component', 'n_intervals')])
def update_text(n):
    return html.Span(f'No of times updated: {n}')


@app.callback(Output('dash-graph', 'figure'),
              [Input('interval-component', 'n_intervals')])
def update_graph(n):
    return _create_fig()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

The update text function is working fine but for some reason the update graph function doesnt work. Can anyone point out what error im doing.Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I removed animate=true and it works